# File path in AJAX

Tags: ajax

My EAR is deployed on AIX server. I want to access JSON files outside my ear in AJAX. right now I am able to access JSON files inside the EAR . How can I provide relative path for these files. Please help.

Comment: select the path after server name like `'https://testsite.com/mydata/data/json/getJson'` then the url for the ajax will be like '/mydata/data/json/getJson'.

Comment: @OP: You could quote here (copy+paste) the command/url/etc that works, and also the command/url/etc you would like to work.

Comment: I want to access file by this path : w2ui['grid'].load('/global/myfile/test.json'). AJAX requires relative path so how can I provide this path relatively? Because when I provide this path it takes it as : www.testing.com/global/myfile/test.json. and it gives error as "Unable to find the URL". Thank you in advance :)